# Normalizer transformation in Informatica to Convert Columns to rows Based on a ID Column

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

| POLICY_NUMBER | AGENT_NUMBER_1 | AGNT_PCT_RT_1 | AGENT_NUMBER_2 | AGNT_PCT_RT_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SC123456789 | CL00022250 | 50 | CL00050083 | 25 |

The Data should be Normalized in Informatica like shown below Using Normalization Transformation :

SC123456789 ---> CL00022250 ----> 50

SC123456789 ---> CL00050083 ----> 25

Comment: could you pls share what you have done? This seems to be a standard normalizer problem.

Comment: we have used a Source Qualifier query which gives the Output as shown above , where a single POLICY_NUMBER is used by different AGENT_NUMBER_1 and AGENT_NUMBER_3 hence we need the Data to be split from column to rows Using a Informatica Normalizer transformation . I don't know how to achieve it in informatica normalizer hence posted the query here .